# how can I execute all row in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

In database table I have age column in which have more than 50 rows.

```
id age

1 45

2 41

3 09

......

60 11
```

I always have 10 keys in array ,

```
<?php
    $arr = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    echo json_encode($arr)."<br>";    
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','app_user2','qwe123','test');
    $select="select age from ad;";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $select);                      
    while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr=array_slice($arr,1,9);
        //$arr[]=$row['id'];
         $arr[]=array($i++, (int)$row['age']);
        echo json_encode($arr)."<br>";
   }
?>
```

I'm getting following output=>

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[0,45]]

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[0,45],[1,41]]

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[0,45],[1,41],[2,11]]

[0,0,0,0,0,0,[0,45],[1,41],[2,11],[3,21]]

[0,0,0,0,0,[0,45],[1,41],[2,11],[3,21],[4,44]]

.............................
[[1,41],[2,11],[3,21],[4,44],[5,13],[6,15],[7,12],[8,7],[9,14],[10,11]]

........................
```

Now when i execute

> echo json_encode($arr)

in JavaScript i'm getting only last 10 values. i want to execute all the rows one by one. how can i do that? Is it possible?please help.

here is my `script code`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data=[];
    data=<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
    document.write(data);
</script>
```

Comment: surrountd with quotes, ` data="<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>";`

Answer (score 1):

That's because your string isn't in a valid json format. Then you get output of just one line. You may consider build in a correct way like:

```
$myArray = []
while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr=array_slice($arr,1,9);
    //$arr[]=$row['id'];
     $arr[]=array($i++, (int)$row['age']);
    array_push($myArray, $arr);
}
```

then:

```
data=<?php echo json_encode($myArray ); ?>;
```

(PS.: hardcode server side code in javascript isn't a good practice)

Answer (score 0):

On each run through the loop, you assign `$arr` using `array_slice` and assign 9 elements to it (starting from element 1, length 9). Later in the loop iteration, you add a new element to the end of the array with a `$arr[] = ...` assignment.

Since you are assigning the array to have 9 elements and then adding 1 element on each iteration, it will always end up being 10 elements long at most, and no more.